# thread_local x(2) doesn't call constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, ssl, thread-local-storage

`thread_local` is defined in C++11 to have dynamic initialization semantics, so that it is permissible to declare non-POD types as thread local.  However, in this program, I get an unexpected result:

```
#include <iostream>
struct A {
  A() : repr_(0) {}
  A(int) : repr_(2) {}
  int repr_;
};
thread_local A x(2);
int main() {
  std::cerr << x.repr_ << "\n";
  return 0;
}
```

On GCC 4.8 I get:

```
$ g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36)
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

$ g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp && ./a.out
0
```

The program works correctly if I replace the `thread_local` line with:

```
thread_local A x = A(2);
```

What's going on here?

Comment: Works with gcc 5.4 -- bug in the older compiler?